# PHP remove tags matching pattern or wild card pattern

Tags: php

How can I use preg_replace or similar to find and replace all instances where tags matche the following:

I have many instances of tags like this in my content:

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"></span>
<span style="background-color: rgb(125, 125, 0);"></span>
<span style="*"></span> (background-color could be anything...)
```

How can I remove only the tags where nothing is in between the span tag but leave others where there is content in between the span tags.

**I want to remove these...**

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"></span> (background-color is wild)
```

**I want to leave these...**

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Content...</span>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in PHP? Can you describe how these get into your structure in the first place?

Comment: Is using DOMDocument an option?

Comment: Yes, it has to be done with PHP. This happens because users use Summernote and content needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Yes, DOMDocument is an option.

Comment: Load it into DOMDocument, scan for empty nodes (ie. nodes where `->childNodes->length === 0`) and remove them. Done. Regex is 100% the wrong tool for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is the best tool for this job.
You capture all `span` elements and if any span element has no child nodes(including text nodes), then remove that from the DOM. In the end, you need to [`saveHTML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to dump the HTML string.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$html = '
<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">a</span>
<span style="background-color: rgb(125, 125, 0);">b<b>ldkf</b></span>
<span style="*"></span>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span_node){
    if($span_node->childNodes->length == 0){ // if no child nodes, then remove it
        $span_node->parentNode->removeChild($span_node);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Also, since regex is a bad practice, I am adding the way in the comments and _not including_ it in my answer `echo preg_replace('/<span\s.+?><\/span>/','',$html);`